Extra space produced by custom `ifenv`
I am using an ifenv macro to create slightly different formatting depending on the environment a command is used in. The macro is defined as following:
\makeatletter
\def\ifenv#1{
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
}
\makeatother

It mostly works fine. However, when the arguments passed into the macro is empty, there is an additional space produced.
For example, the following code
no\ifenv{lstlisting}{}{}space

will produce a space in between "no" and "space."
How can I fix this behavior and have it not producing the extra space?


Add a line-ending % after the opening brace of your \definition: \def\ifenv#1{%

Thanks a lot, that solved the issue!
